# UIBarButtonItems in iOS 7 are slow

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios7, uiappearance

I build the app I am working on for iOS 7 and ran it on an iPad 2. I noticed it was markedly slower than when build for iOS 6. I did some investigating and found that the main point of slowness was in setting the UINavigationBar's UIBarButtonItems. This seemed weird as I hadn't noticed this in other applications but since I use UIAppearance to customise the buttons in this app i thought that might have something to do with it. So I commented the UIAppearance code out and the app was back to normal. I still wish to use the custom appearance though so I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this or has some insight into it.

I should add that the app works fine in the simulator.

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing this too. It seems like the solution is to avoid using UIAppearance on UIBarButtonItems. This is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144139/cache-eraseimp-nolock-taking-very-long-in-ios-7

Comment: I'll try not using UIAppearance and see what happens. I actually switched over to iOS 7 style buttons for the time being which seemed to help.