# cache_eraseImp_nolock taking very long in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have an app that's been in production for a while, but on iOS 7 there is a noticeable delay in transitions after interacting with the app for a bit. I used time profiler to see what's taking long, and `cache_eraseImp_nolock` seems to be the culprit. (It's taking more time than `objc_msgSend`!) It seems like this is called when view controller transition happens. (Pushing a view controller, presenting a modal view controller, etc.)

Did anyone see something similar? What can I do to prevent this problem?

I'm trying to reproduce this issue with an app built from scratch, but no luck so far.

[image: Instruments Screenshot]

Comment: Are you still using UIAppearance anywhere?  iOS 7's been deprecating quite a bit of it.

Comment: @CodaFi Yes! I was using UIAppearance for UINavigationController bar items and removing those fixed the problem. Thanks! The methods that were used weren't deprecated, so maybe I will file a bug about that.

Comment: You go ahead and do that, I'll put that up as the answer so this doesn't get relegated to the unanswered questions section.

Comment: I don't see any deprecation in API diffs. Where did you find out about deprecated UIAppearance APIs?

Comment: It's being phased out internally.  There's lots of little problems with it that are intentional at this point.

Comment: @CodaFi So, is not advisable to use UIAppearance? the above issue is bad on iOS7.0.x. Can anyone confirm on iOS7.1 if its fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>iOS 7.0 has been phasing out UIAppearance and making it unstable in some cases.  Check your calls to UIAppearance-based APIs and remove them if necessary.</strike>*

iOS 7.1 seems to have fixed a lot of what was wrong before and sped up UIAppearance's interactions with the runtime.  Still, the semantics of UIAppearance have changed drastically since iOS 6.  Exercise caution.

<sub>*This was only partially true while the iOS 7 beta SDKs were out.</sub>

Comment: This was very convenient on previous versions. iOS7 is when we needed UIAppearance to work the MOST. Are you sure about it being phased out? I don't see any indication as such. I assume the alternate way would be the old brute force method?

Comment: @user134611 Wow, this one's old.  There was a time while watching the iOS 7 SDKs go flying when it seemed like UIAppearance was on the chopping block.  They must have ultimately decided against it, and it's much improved in 7.1.

Comment: thanks for replying. Prior to 7.1, UIAppearance remains horrible, which is bothering me to the point where I'm thinking of making my 7.1 a minimum requirement. UIAppearance solves some great problems, the above issue is just insane (in practise).

Answer (score 5):

UIAppearance is glacially slow on iOS7.0.x.  By the above stack trace, it appears that applying appearance methods gets method_exchangeImplementations() called every time (or at least many times), which in turn has to clear out caches in the ObjC runtime for the targeted class and all subclasses, and it will hold a global lock while it does that -- very slow.  I have no idea if UIAppearance changed, or there was a change in the ObjC runtime which made this case much more pathologically slow than it used to be.

In addition, I think I've seen that the UILabel setShadowOffset: and setShadowColor: methods are also very slow, as they appear to be appearance-swizzled versions and thus have the same problem (despite the fact they are not labeled UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR).

One overall solution is to just not use UIAppearance as much or at all.  For the UILabel methods, check first to see if the value needs changing, and don't call the setters if not needed.

Another possible solution is [CTAppearance](https://github.com/Collect3/CTAppearance) which is a re-implementation of UIAppearance, at least for the UIView-based calls (it does not do anything with UIBarItem appearance calls, which remain slow).  It needs some patches currently just in the pull requests, and will not handle UIPopover containers without some help.  Its behavior will also be a bit different than UIAppearance (for example it may override some explicitly-set values depending on when they are called) but it may help (a lot) in some situations.

**Note:** UIAppearance seems to be fixed in iOS 7.1.

Comment: Can someone confirm if this is fixed in 7.1? This bug is completely debilitating for any interactive transitions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Apple has already fixed the problem in iOS 7.1, but for those planning to support iOS7, I have uploaded a fairly straightforward workaround to Github: [SGVAppearanceProxy](https://github.com/sanekgusev/SGVAppearanceProxy).

This is not an UIAppearance reimplementation, but merely a proxy designed to seamlessly wrap the original `-[UIView appearance]`.

The implementation is based on the observation that only appearance methods taking more than one argument and methods with axis values are the ones causing the extensive trip to `cache_eraseImp_nolock()`.

This is basically a proxy over the original proxy which uses Objective-C's forwarding mechanism to capture NSInvocations of appearance methods before they are sent to the original appearance proxy, adds unique new selectors to the target class with a method signature taking an NSInvocation as a single argument, and finally constructs a new NSInvocation passing the original one as an argument. This invocation is then invoked on the original proxy. The IMP for the custom selectors then just calls the original invocation without any expensive swizzling performed by the original UIAppearance logic.

Do note that this only works on UIViews, because the non-UIView UIAppearance-enabled classes (e. g. UIBarButtonItem) have a private internal view class that all appearance invocations are routed to, so there seems to be no *legal* way to add custom selectors to those classes.

Comment: thanks for posting. I do get this latency issue even if I just use the `[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor]`. Don't think its limited to just axis values. Could you help me out a bit, Never really used NSProxy, how do I implement SGVAppearanceProxy?

Comment: Do note that using a stored NSInvocation which retains its arguments will also retain all targets it is invoked with, and will not release them until the NSInvocation itself is dealloced.  Setting the target to nil will not help (all arguments/targets simply get added to an internal NSArray, which is never cleared).  I'm not entirely sure if your code has that problem with a quick look, but if it does, you can end up leaking every UIAppearance target, which adds up fast :-)  CTAppearance has a pull request which fixes that issue there.

Comment: @CarlLindberg The target retain semantics in NSInvocations were not clear to me, thanks for pointing those out! If a mere invokeWithTarget: does indeed retain the target for the lifetime of invocation instance, then the code definitely needs to be fixed. I'll take a look at the aforementioned pull request, thanks!